# Error while saving an user input in spring application. Additional problem with catalog controller

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

a group of friends and I create a Hotel website application in Spring. I am responsible for the room catalog part. I've created some classes in java, `Room.java`, `RoomCategory.java`, `CatalogController.java`, `RoomCatalog.java`, and 2 HTML files `welcome.html` and `roomCatalog.html`.

My problem is that when I want to save the input value-form user e.g `th:field="*{name}"` in `roomCatalog.html`the website crashes.

```
<form method="post" role="form" th:action="@{/addNewCategory}" th:object="${roomCategory}" >

         <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Categories</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" th:field="*{name}" required="required" /> 
            </div>
</form>
```

The second problem is in `RoomCatalog.java` with the method `findByCategory()`, it returns null now, which is wrong, but when I delate the body of the function and `default` at the beginning, my application crashes while booting.

```
default Iterable<Room> findByCategory(RoomCategory roomCategory, Sort sort){
        return null;
    }
```

Could you help me find and eliminate the problem?

`Room.java`

```
package hotelwebsite.catalog;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.salespointframework.catalog.Product;

@Entity
public class Room extends Product {

    private String name;
    private int roomNumber, floor;
    private String image;

    private RoomCategory roomCategory;


    private Room(){}

    public Room(String name, int roomNumber, int floor, RoomCategory roomCategory) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.floor = floor;
        this.roomCategory = roomCategory;
    }

    public int getRoomNumber() {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public int getFloor() {
        return floor;
    }

    public RoomCategory getRoomCategory() {
        return roomCategory;
    }

    public void editImage(String image){
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

`RoomCategory.java`

```
package hotelwebsite.catalog;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.javamoney.moneta.Money;
import org.salespointframework.catalog.Product;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class RoomCategory implements Serializable {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private final int sleepingPlaces, addSleepingPlaces;

    private String name;
    private Money price;

    public RoomCategory(String name, int sleepingPlaces, int addSleepingPlaces, Money price) {
        this.sleepingPlaces = sleepingPlaces;
        this.addSleepingPlaces = addSleepingPlaces;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName(){ return name; }

    public String getPrice(){
        return this.price.toString();
    }

    public int getSleepingPlaces() {
        return sleepingPlaces;
    }

    public int getAddSleepingPlaces() { return addSleepingPlaces; }

    public int getMaxSleepingPlaces(){
        return (sleepingPlaces + addSleepingPlaces);
    }
}
```

`RoomCatalog.java`

```
package hotelwebsite.catalog;

import hotelwebsite.catalog.Room;

import org.salespointframework.catalog.Catalog;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

public interface RoomCatalog extends Catalog<Room> {

    static final Sort DEFAULT_SORT = Sort.by("productName").descending();


    default Iterable<Room> findByCategory(RoomCategory roomCategory, Sort sort){
        return null;
    }

    default Iterable<Room> findByRoomCategory(RoomCategory roomCategory) {
        return findByCategory(roomCategory, DEFAULT_SORT);
    }
}
```

`CatalogController.java`

```
package hotelwebsite.catalog;

import hotelwebsite.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.salespointframework.inventory.InventoryItem;
import org.salespointframework.inventory.UniqueInventory;
import org.salespointframework.inventory.UniqueInventoryItem;
import org.salespointframework.time.BusinessTime;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


@Controller
public class CatalogController {

    private final RoomCatalog catalog;
    private final UniqueInventory<UniqueInventoryItem> inventory;
    private final BusinessTime businessTime;

    public CatalogController(RoomCatalog roomCatalog,
                             UniqueInventory<UniqueInventoryItem> inventory,
                             BusinessTime businessTime) {

        this.catalog = roomCatalog;
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.businessTime = businessTime;
    }

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    String roomCategoryCatalog(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("catalog", catalog);

        return "roomCatalog";
    }

    @GetMapping("/rooms")
    String roomCatalog(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("catalog", catalog);

        return "roomCatalog";
    }


    @GetMapping("/room/{room}")
    String detail(@PathVariable Room room, Model model) {


        model.addAttribute("room", room);

        return "detail";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewCategory")
    public String addRoomCategory(RoomCategory roomCategory, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("roomCategory",roomCategory);
        model.addAttribute("catalog", roomCategory);
        //System.out.println(roomCategory + " added to catalog.");

        return "roomCatalog";

    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteCategory")
    public String deleteRoomCategory(RoomCategory roomCategory, Model model){

        //model.addAttribute("catalog", roomCategory);
        return(roomCategory + " deleted from catalog.");
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewRoom")
    public String addRoom(Room room, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("catalog", room);
        //return(room + " added to catalog.");
        return "redirect:/categories";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteRoom")
    public String deleteRoom(Room room, Model model){

        //model.deleteAttribute("catalog", room);
        return(room + " deleted from catalog.");
    }

    @PostMapping("/editImage")
    public String editImage(Room room, Model model, String image){
        return null;
    }
}
```

`welcome.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" />
        <title>welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <div class="roomCatalog">
            <a href="roomCatalog.html" th:href="@{/categories}">Room Catalog</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`roomCatalog.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" />
    <title>Room Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui container">

        <header>
            <h1> Willkommen im Hotel</h1>
        </header>

        <form method="post" role="form" th:action="@{/addNewCategory}" th:object="${roomCategory}" >

            <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Categories</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required="required" /> <!-- th:field="*{name}" -->
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="sleepingPlaces">Sleeping places</label>
                <input id="sleepingPlaces" name="sleepingPlaces" type="number" required="required" /> <!--th:field="*{sleepingPlaces}"-->
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="addSleepingPlaces"> Extra sleeping places</label>
                <input id="addSleepingPlaces" name="addSleepingPlaces" type="number"/> <!--th:field="*{addSleepingPlaces}"-->
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input id="price" name="getPrice()" type="number" required="required" /> <!-- th:field="*{price}" -->
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="ui button">Add Category</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I understand this correct that `findByCategory` returning null in `return null;` is just placeholder code until you get to actually implement the method? In that case you could try returning an empty list or another iterable instead of null. eG. `return Collections.emptyList();`

Comment: Yeah, it's only a placeholder. As i understood, it should return a list of room categories, but i don't know how to code that.